# Conditional formatting using cell styles in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Excel 2007 has added support for cell styles, which I find very useful. I love it when I can change formatting in one place and the change propagates throughout the spreadsheet.

I also love conditional formatting.

Can the two be combined? Can I conditionally apply a cell *style*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't conditionally **apply** a style, but you can conditionally **remove** it. If you format the cell with the style that you ultimately want, then depending on the situation, you can then clear that style with the conditional formatting.

Comment: Good idea, might work in some cases. This time I was hoping to apply different styles depending on a formula though.

Comment: You could probably do it with VBA, but it would be messy and slow.

Comment: Accepted for "You can't conditionally apply a style".